# How can I extract a variable with eclipse and convert it into a class?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have the problem that I defined a HashMap as a variable, where I should have used a class for better extendability.

I would like eclipse to refactor the

```
HashMap<String, Integer> result
```

variable into my result class type, that I can then extend. How can I accomplish this, considering that the `HashMap` is used throughout my project?

I would like to have the result to be not a `HashMap`, but an Object.

```
public class result {
     HashMap<String, Integer> res;
     public void setres(String res, int res) {

     }
}
```

Comment: How do you want it to look like if you're using a method which returns a `HashMap`?

Comment: You could have the result class extend HashMap (or Map) to keep the functionality consistent.

Comment: Consider using a `Map` on the left-hand side of your code

Answer (score 1):

Just start replacing.  Create your class, with its own HashMap field, and somewhere in your code replace the HashMap with YourClass.  Now you'll see some red underlines where your class doesn't implement the (HashMap) method.  Use QuickFix to create the missing method, then (short term) delegate the call straight through to the field.  You'll see some other underline, say, where you're passing the YourClass to a method that expects a HashMap.  QuickFix that so the method now expects a YourClass, and the fix the bugs you see there.  Repeat until done.

Answer (score 1):

While Carl Manaster answer is absolutely right, I would recommend a different aproach, extending HashMap itself. So you only need to rewrite the constructor and you override all the HashMap methods, and it's possible to add any other fields or custom methods you would need.

First you make a class like this:

```
class ResultHashMap extends HashMap<String, Integer> {
 //Add all your customization here        
}
```

Then you replace all your ocurrences of:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> reslut = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

To:

```
ResultHashMap result = new ResultHashMap();
```